# Are there advantages of using the $log provider for angular?

Tags: angularjs

I read an article regarding angular and in it the author posits that angular developers must utilize the $log provider. What advantages does the $log provider provide over plain old console.log? It seems like it adds another depedency to my applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular's `$log` will check if the browser supports `console` and won't throw an error if it does not (IE8).

You can also decorate your messages and mock it in order to unit test your application.

In addition, you can also use the `$logProvider` to turn on/off logging.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest advantage is that you can set up logging for non-production environments and turn off logging in production with one setting

```
$logProvider.debugEnabled(true)
```